# Quick way to freeze and unfreeze columns in Google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am making an inventory system in Google spreadsheets and I eventually need to freeze all of the columns besides location to ensure that fields do not accidentally get messed up.  However, we will also be adding new inventory which leads me to believe I will have to unfreeze all the other fields each time I add a new machine.  How can I get around this?  open to any suggestions to meet my needs as I am not dead set on Google spreadsheet but need a free way for multiple users to manipulate data from around the globe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you're still looking for an answer, but you could use the setFrozenRows method in a script for that 
(see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet?hl=ja#setFrozenRows%28Integer%29)

Answer (score 0):

setFrozenRows(rows) - Freezes the given number of rows. If zero, no rows are frozen.

> var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
>
> var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
>
> sheet.setFrozenRows(1); // Freezes the first row